# Best design for adding a folder/file relationship

Tags: database-design

I was given a database that has Projects and Media_files.  They were in a simple 1 to many relationship.

I now need to add Folders to Projects.  Media_files can be placed in Folders, and Folders can have Folders within them.

I am at a loss as to the best way to, first, have Folders belong to other Folders, and second, the best way to maintain the current relationship between Projects and Media_files, or if its best to break this relationship.

Projects is a simple table:

```
id, 
title, 
description, 
owner_id.
```

Folders are an entirely new table, but my basic idea for them was:

```
id, 
project_id, 
parent_folder_id, 
title, 
description
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it would help you to be able to maintain the current relationship between `Projects` and `Media_files`, you could make "Folders" a kind of `Project`. The usual way to do this would be to add a `parent_project_id` to `Projects` referring to the same table, eg:

```
create table projects(project_id serial primary key, ...);

alter table projects add parent_project_id references projects;
```

Then

- `Folders` are all `Projects`, or all `Projects` with a non-null `parent_project_id` depending on which suits you best
- The old `Projects` maps to all `Projects` with a null `parent_project_id`

Comment: This method works best for my project.  It saves a bunch of re-writes in existing code.  And, as always seems to be the case, speed is of the essence in this project.

Answer (score 3):

I would to it either like this

```
       Projets
-----------------------
     project_id
       [....]

       Folder
-----------------------
     folder_id
     parent_id (-1 or the matching parent folder)
     project_id
      [....]

      Media   
-----------------------
     media_id
     folder_id
     [....]
```

This way, you would need to break the relationship for it to work. IF you want to maintain the relationship, I would screw normalisation over, and add a `project_id` to the `Media` table as well with proper constraints/trigger so that moving media from one folder to another work without writing the explicit query.

---

or the other way would be:

```
       Projets
-----------------------
     project_id
       [....]

       Folder
-----------------------
     folder_id
     parent_id (-1 or the matching parent folder)
      [....]

      Media   
-----------------------
     media_id
     folder_id
     project_id
      [....]
```

You maintain the original relationship and are good to go.

Comment: "(-1 or the matching parent folder)" why not NULLABLE? NULL or the matching parent folder. Then you can add a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Also possible, it depends more on your liking of "NULL" values.